# WPF - Is it possible to assign an event in a Style?

Tags: wpf, events, xaml

Specifically I want all PasswordBox's using a Style to have the same static KeyDown event handler - would it be possible to somehow set this in the Style they are using rather than setting it on each PasswordBox? (which I am having to do in code behind at the moment as they all point to the same static handler)..

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`EventSetter` is your friend. As for the handler - just put it into code-behind (you can create a code-behind for a resource dictionary too - just crate a CS file with the same name as the dictionary and add the class attribute to the resource dictionary XAML).

Small example:

```
<Style>
    <EventSetter Event="KeyDown" Handler="KeyDownHandler"/>
</Style>
```